# Entity Framework - Related Entity Perfomance

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, entities

i have an query to load related entity for an specific entity, but it´s take a 5 seconds to load data, what happened?

```
var rows = clientes.Select(c => new
        {
            c.Id,
            c.Nome,
            Telefone = String.Format("(0{0}) {1}", c.DDD, c.Telefone),
            c.Email,
            Veiculo = (from v in c.Veiculos select new { v.Id, v.Modelo, v.Chassi }),
        })
    .Skip(pageNumber > 1 ? qtdRows * (pageNumber - 1) : 0)
    .Take(qtdRows)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL that EF is sending to the server?

Comment: As an aside, I think you need an OrderBy clause for the Skip to reliably return the expected subset of entities.

Comment: Well your `Veiculo` select is pulling down the *entire* table for *every* record, my guess is that's the problem.

Comment: Is it first query to database in runtime? If so, you should mind the "warm up" problem of Entity Framework http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250679/how-to-warm-up-entity-framework-when-does-it-get-cold

Comment: It's probably because it's an outer join. Or you should add indexes in the database.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you join two entities but not using filter to get Veiculos of current Clientes.

May be you should use something like

```
var rows = clientes.Select(c => new
        {
            c.Id,
            c.Nome,
            Telefone = String.Format("(0{0}) {1}", c.DDD, c.Telefone),
            c.Email,
            Veiculo = (from v in c.Veiculos *where v.ClientId == c.Id* select new { v.Id, v.Modelo, v.Chassi }),
        })
    .Skip(pageNumber > 1 ? qtdRows * (pageNumber - 1) : 0)
    .Take(qtdRows)
    .ToArray();
```

**But, more consistent method is to add navigation property Veiculo to entity Client and lay joining of tables on Entity Framework.**

Comment: With where it´s down time from 5.60s to 4.68s, in the Client entity i have an navigation property like public virtual IList<Veiculo> Veiculos { get; set; }

Comment: I´m using Repository Pattern with NInject(DI), first, i´m getting the clientes, IList<Cliente> clientes = (from c in _clienteRepository.Get(c => c.CodigoDealer == dealer.Codigo).Include(v => v.Veiculos) select c).Include(b=>b.Beneficios).ToList();, if remove this line (from v in c.Veiculos *where v.ClientId == c.Id* select new { v.Id, v.Modelo, v.Chassi }), it´s very fast!

Comment: The explicit `where` doesn't make sense here, `c.Veiculos` is a navigation property therefore the `where` is implied.

Comment: exact, in the original query i did´t wrote, but it´s strange, the query was optimized with where clause, so i don´t known why with navigation property the query is so slow...

Comment: Could you check what sql requests is posted to Sql server and post it in your question? Use sql profiler.

Comment: I´m using VS2010 Professional Edition, so sql profiler isn't avaiable, but i did the traced with EFProf and see details...           SELECT [Extent1].[ID_VEICULO] AS [ID_VEICULO],
       [Extent1].[ID_CLIENTE] AS [ID_CLIENTE],
       [Extent1].[Modelo]     AS [Modelo],
       [Extent1].[Chassi]     AS [Chassi]
FROM   [dbo].[TB_IR_VEICULO] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  [Extent1].[ID_CLIENTE] = 10 /* @EntityKeyValue1 */             And one alert that say, Select N + 1 is a data access anti-pattern...