# Entity framework loads slowly first time (DB First Model)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first

I read all the post out there where they all posted that EF loads very slow for the first time. But all the answers were for Code first model. My question is that, Is there any solution for DB first model.

Please help me. I hope this is not a silly question but i am really stuck at this place.

Thnx in advance.

Comment: update to EF6 if you still use EF4 or 5 or use Views: https://efinteractiveviews.codeplex.com/

Comment: Look through this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250679/how-to-warm-up-entity-framework-when-does-it-get-cold

Comment: Is it also possible when we are using Database First.