# Delay in windows service, when the request was not made for few hours

Tags: c#, sql, windows-services

I'm currently working on windows service code, I'm facing the delay in reading the next request data from SQL server database, If I didn't make request for few hours, So I'm force to insert some data and deleting it from DB. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Are you saying that you getting a delay reading from SQL if a few hours has elapsed since the last DB operation?  if so, just maintain a true and small pool of connections that you can keep alive with non data altering commands

Comment: If you are getting a delay, then it is probably a credential check which is done against a password server.  How much of a delay are you getting and is it critical.  Keeping the connection open like Micky suggested is one solution.

Comment: Are you using entity framework? If so, maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250679/how-to-warm-up-entity-framework-when-does-it-get-cold

Comment: Thanks. like @MickyD said, I'm already maintaining small pool of connections to keep alive, Why its happening and what can I do to avoid this.

Comment: It's an expense that happens when your app first starts or when you haven't used the resource in a while.  The OS ultimately releases the resource which is expensive to re-create later.  You can observe this phenomena whether it is a database connection (we had this back in the 90s for ODBC);  network connections such as WCF.   It most likely falls under the category of _deferred initialisation_