# EF6 slow first query implications on deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Knowing that Entity Framework is slow on a cold query (first query after model compilation), I am doing some of the standard work around methods to speed it up. Mainly pre-compiled views as well as making a dummy http request on the client side as soon as the application loads to trigger a query to start the model process.

My question here is specifically around how this works for a deployed application. For example, if I deploy this on Azure, is it the first cold query for the *entire application* that will trigger the model compilation, or will this slow cold query happen for each *individual user* that uses the application? In simple terms, does it happen once and only once, or every time a user hits the site for a new session?

Comment: i believe the cold query is for the entire application, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13605621/4648586).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EF slow start is triggered from the first request/s coming into the web server that requires database services.

A couple points to note,

- If you deploy to an Azure web app, ensure that the 'AlwaysOn' application setting is enabled. If not, after a given time period the web app will be suspended and the next request will trigger another cold start.
- Similarly if you deploy to a VM with IIS you'll need to check the application recycling settings.
- When you deploy a new version of the application code, the process will need to be restarted which will cause another slow start.

A good approach to mitigate such slow starts is by using deployment slots and pre-warming slots before sending actual user traffic to it. This is straightforward to achieve using Azure Web App deployment slots.