# "AlwaysRunning" not working

Tags: asp.net, iis

We have IIS version 6.2 for running an ASP.net application.
We have a application pool for this web application.
The .net framework version is "4.0".
"Startmodus" is "AlwaysRunning".

Why is the first access of a user always slow?

I found several questions releated to this topic but I cannot see why "AlwaysRunning" is not helping here.

[image: Application Pool Settings]

Is it a good idea to create a powershell script accesssing the web application every 15 minutes in order to avoid this "IIS sleep mode"?

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387123/how-to-warm-up-an-asp-net-mvc-application-on-iis-7-5

Comment: I am using http://uptimerobot.com/ now. It Triggers a request every 15 minutes. But I cannot believe that it is that complicated to solve it in IIS by one or two Settings.

Comment: Usually sites that have some users, did not fall on this category. You site is a rare case. If you have for example 10-20 public sites under a pool, the crawler never allow that to happen. If you have a private site, under one pool, then is happends

Answer (score 5):

a little late to the party, but it seems what you need is either set the Idle Time-out to zero (default is 20) means every 20 minutes the application pool will be restarted. [Source](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/522#issuecomment-164381473)

Also there is a tag in web.config, to tell iis to send a fake request to you app at start up , to make sure you app is completley initialized :

```
<applicationInitialization
   remapManagedRequestsTo="Startup.htm"
   skipManagedModules="true" >
   <add initializationPage="/default.aspx" />
</applicationInitialization>
```

[Source](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/iis-8-0-application-initialization-for-fast-startup-everytime)

Comment: The link `http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/iis-8-0-application-initialization-for-fast-startup-everytime` is very useful. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had to install the 'Application Initialization' feature of IIS (only IIS 8+ I think).

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/applicationinitialization.

Furthermore I had to set following settings: 
App pool: StartMode always running 
The page: Preload enabled

And finally recycle the app pool for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

AlwaysRunning means that it won't shut down if it's idle.

So, you need to configure Auto Start as well:

1. In IIS Manager, click computer name in the Connection pane.
2. Switch to Features View if the view is not active.
3. Double-click Configuration Editor in the Management section of the
   Features View.
4. Click the down-arrow for the Section field, expand
   system.applicationhost, and then click application pools.
5. Click (Collection) and then click eclipses (…) next to the field
   that shows the count.
6. In the Collection Editor, select the application pool for which you
   want to configure the startMode attribute.
7. In the Properties window at the bottom, set the value of autoStart
   attribute to True.

Complete info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677285%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed instructions. The property "autoStart" is true already and it does not work.

Comment: Do I Need to increase shutdownTimeLimit? this would affect the worker process. Is it the worker process that Needs to Keep running?

Comment: @Matthias nope, default value is fine

Comment: It seems there is no clear answer for this issue. I setup a bot calling the site every 15 minutes to keep it fast.